# Save datetime with timezone in Postgres table

Tags: postgresql, timezone-offset

I am trying to save datetime with timezone in Postgres but can not find anything usefull.

Input would be like,

```
2021-03-21T12:24:30Z
2021-03-21T12:24:30PST'
```

and i am expecting output in the datetime column like,

```
'2001-02-16 18:38:40+05:30'
'2001-02-16 18:38:40+00'
```

what would be the datatype in column and what's the way i can save the date time including timezone.

Comment: See here [Date/times](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the TIMESTAMPTZ data type for the column - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html